# Android Studio listView Add and Search

Tags: android, listview

I have a task to make an Android application with a `ListView`, which must have an add button and search system. I have watched a few tutorials ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9yC8XGaSv4 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LgEk3Cg9Yk) and using both tutorials I have developed a program. The program can do both things, but there is a bug. When I first run the app, I add a few items and then I use the search functionality. The search works just fine, but after the search has been used once, it is no longer working.

Below is my code:

```
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private EditText txtInput;
SearchView searchView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listv);

        String Items[]={};

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Items));

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        txtInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtinput);

        Button btAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btadd);

        searchView = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView1);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
                return false;
            }
        });

        btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String newItem = txtInput.getText().toString();
                arrayList.add(newItem);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: try to set btAdd into global variable.

Comment: I tried it, didn't work :/